# How to convert a list with plain data to allow key filters

Tags: key-filter

I have a project where I have created a list with several fields.  I can see from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6764/key-field-list-filter-on-plain-text-field-in-sp2010) that it is not possible to filter on the plain text fields that I have holding e-mail aliases.  How can I go about modifying the list to allow key filtering, and what changes will I have to do to the InfoPath form that populates the list?